# Resetting object key values

Tags: javascript

I'm here today because i'm unable to figure a problem out by myself. I have the following object:

```
var obj = {
    "type": "name",
    "param1": 10,
    "param2": "text",
    "param3": "more_text",
    "param4": 20
}
```

Now what i want to do it to reset all the values that each key holds to 0, so that the next time i call this object, all the values were reset to *0*;

What i have tried but it doesn't work is the following:

```
Object.prototype.reset = function(){
  for(var i in this){
    if(typeof this[i] != 'function'){
        if(i == 'type'){
            i = this[i];
     }
     else{
            i = 0;
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Of all the keys, i only want *'type'* to keep its value while the rest should be reset to 0;

**Note:** the line

```
if(typeof this[i] != 'function'){
```

is there because for some reason, `this[i]` returns the source code of the method and i want to avoid getting into that. If there is any solution for that, would be nice but i didn't manage to work that out.

The end result should look something like:

```
var obj = {
    "type": "name",
    "param1": 10,
    "param2": "text",
    "param3": "more_text",
    "param4": 20
}
```

obj.reset()

```
var obj = {
    "type": "name",
    "param1": 0,
    "param2": 0,
    "param3": 0,
    "param4": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the object value `this[i]` rather than the property `i`.

Your code should be something like:

```js
var obj = {
  "type": "name",
  "param1": 10,
  "param2": "text",
  "param3": "more_text",
  "param4": 20
}

Object.prototype.reset = function() {
  for (var i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] != 'function') {
      if (i == 'type') {
        i = this[i];
      } else {
        this[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

obj.reset();

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: i was so tunnel visioned on everything else, that i missed this mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop in the object and clear all properties like this:

```
for(var key in Object.keys(obj)) { 
   if(typeof key !== 'function') {
     obj[key] = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren`t changing the original object, only the reference. You could do:

`this[i] = 0` instead `i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` returns an array of an object's keys and is more suitable than using a `for in` loop.

Try this:

```
Object.prototype.reset = function(){
    Object.keys(this).forEach(e => this[e] = 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code you might be interested in

```
var obj1 = {
    "type": "name",
    "param1": 10,
    "param2": "text",
    "param3": "more_text",
    "param4": 20
}

obj1.reset = function(){
    for(ele in this){
        if(ele!='type'){
          this[ele]="0";
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj1);
obj1.reset();
console.log(obj1);
```